# How to add an input-group-addon ( Bootstrap CSS ) onto an Alpaca.js field

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, handlebars.js, alpacajs

Hoping for some assistance , I require an appended and prepended Input group addon [As shown here on bootstrap.com](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) into a alpaca.js form.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">@example.com</span>
</div>
```

The template (handlebars) should look like the snippet below, however documentation on the site does not cover custom options and template editing like this.

```html
 <script type="text/x-handlebars-template">

  {{#if options.component}}
  <div class="input-group">
   {{#if options.prepend}}
   <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon-prepend">{{options.prepend}}</span>
   {{/if}}
 {{/if}}

   <input type="{{inputType}}" id="{{id}}" {{#if options.placeholder}}placeholder="{{options.placeholder}}"{{/if}} {{#if options.size}}size="{{options.size}}"{{/if}} {{#if options.readonly}}readonly="readonly"{{/if}} {{#if name}}name="{{name}}"{{/if}} {{#each options.data}}data-{{@key}}="{{this}}"{{/each}} {{#each options.attributes}}{{@key}}="{{this}}"{{/each}}/>

  {{#if options.component}}
   {{#if options.append}}
   <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon-append">{{options.append}}</span>
   {{/if}}
  </div>
  {{/if}}
  
 </script>
```

The question would be : Where should this code be changed ,and how should the modified template be executed ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If you're tring to use a custom template for a field you should set it into view object like this :

```
"view": {
    "fields": {
        "/username": {
            "templates": {
                "control-text": "#input-group-addon-template"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/rd0jc39k/2/) for this. If this isn't what you're looking for please fill me with more details and I'll be glad to help :)

Comment: I noticed that the form validation helpers will not be shown when doing this. Do you perhaps have a work-around for that?